# how to add custom product accessory to product detail page in wordpress(woocommerce)?

Tags: plugins, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

I want to add this accessories drop-down in product detail page. if user add any accessory then accessory price should also add to cart.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
$cnt=2
function custome_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
      $cnt = $cnt + 1;
      echo $cnt."X";
      echo $p_id=$_POST['assessories'];
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($p_id, 1);

}
```

Output: It is adding the same drop-down item many times into the cart, but I want only 1 quantity to add to cart. It seems that add_to_cart function runs many times. What should I do or how to add filter with passing second drop-down product as parameter to add to cart function? So I can add this product also to the cart.

Comment: For your requirement, you need Composite Products. WooCommerce has a plugin for that but plugin is premium plugin.

Comment: How could i create Composite Products ?

Comment: This question is not off-topic for this site, i really want solution for this. You should read 'Rsigel' & 'Jivani Jaydeep' answers, they trying to provide me solution . i really thankful to both of them but both suggest plugins is paid . i don't want to purchase it. I have almost reached to solution . You can check my next question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365050/how-to-add-filter-or-hook-for-woocommerce-add-to-cart .

Comment: Here is my solution for it add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
$cnt=2
function custome_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
      $cnt = $cnt + 1;
      echo $cnt."X";
      echo $p_id=$_POST['assessories'];
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($p_id, 1);

}

Comment: in output- it adding same drop-down item many time in cart but i want only 1 quantity to add to cart. it seems that add_to_cart function run many times. What should i do or how to add filter with passing second drop-down product as parameter to add to cart function ? so i can add this product also in cart.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's currently no free plugin that can do this... however, you can buy [WooCommerce Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) to have this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin [WooCommerce Extra Product Options](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619) 
It's best solution to add custom field on Woocommerce product page