# How to add filter or hook for "woocommerce_add_to_cart"

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook

[image]

I want add to cart two product at the same time, one is original (current) product and second is from drop-down list

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
$cnt=2
function custome_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
      $cnt = $cnt + 1;
      echo $cnt."X";
      echo $p_id=$_POST['assessories'];
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($p_id, 1);

}
```

Output:-
        As you can see in output image below , it adding same drop-down item many time in cart but i want only 1 quantity to add to cart. it seems that add_to_cart function run many times.
What should i do or how to add filter with passing second drop-down product as parameter to add to cart  function ? so i can add this product also in cart.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you try [Composite Products](http://woothemes.com/products/composite-products)

Comment: Composite Products is a paid plugin. i just want second product which having id ($p_id) should also add to cart with original add to cart product.

Comment: Yes, but it does exactly what you are describing.

Answer (score 23):

This should work:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart');
function custom_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $product_id = $_POST['assessories'];
    
    $found = false;
    
    //check if product already in cart
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                $found = true;
        }
        // if product not found, add it
        if ( ! $found )
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    } else {
        // if no products in cart, add it
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
}
```

Based on following source: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/automatically-add-product-to-cart-on-visit/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. I have to add that it is better to put function's code inside `if (isset($_POST['assessories'])) { }` to avoid PHP notices if there's no $_POST input for some reason.

Comment: This info might be useful to some with woocommerce subscriptions: if you want to know if they are doing a 'first time' 'add-to-cart'(actual purchase) or a subscription switch, you have to check if ( isset( $_GET['switch-subscription'] ) ) . In my case I need to prevent users to subscribe to some subscription that they already have (it's a groupd product) as opposed to doing a switch, because they can have only one at the time per our business rules.

Answer (score 12):

The woocommerce "add_to_cart" functions run the hook "woocommerce_add_to_cart". So, in your code "add_to_cart" is run, which is running "woocommerce_add_to_cart" which runs your code, which runs "add_to_cart", etcetera etcetera... You created a recursive loop.

You need to find an alternative way, or stop calling `$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($p_id, 1);` in your own code.

Comment: yes , its like recursive loop . how can i avoid it ? i just want second product which having  id ($p_id) should also add to cart with original add to cart product.

Comment: If you know the product ID's that are bundles, you can exclude them from activating the hook

Comment: how can i exclude product id from activating the hook, can you elaborate or can provide me any example ?

Comment: Some simple if statement? I have no idea how your data is structured.

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is a **variable product** with some attributes!

Anyway if really you want to do that then you just need the remove_action function :

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
function custome_add_to_cart() {
    $p_id=$_POST['assessories'];
    remove_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', __FUNCTION__);
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $p_id );
}
```

This prevents the action from looping indefinitely and is pretty simple.. So it will be added only once for that product. You might want to get the added to cart quantity and give it as a second parameter to the `WC()->cart->add_to_cart` function so they are both the same quantity

The `__FUNCTION__` is a magic PHP tag just giving you the name of the current fucnction as a string, si if the function name is not the same it will still work

Answer (score 0):

This might be old, but have you tried unsetting the assessories param after adding to cart?, this would break the loop.

```
function custome_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if(isset($_POST['assessories'])){
        $cnt = $cnt + 1;
        echo $cnt . "X";
        echo $p_id = $_POST['assessories'];
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($p_id, 1);
        unset($_POST['assessories']);
    }
}
```