# How to edit function of add to cart of variable product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried finding php files for "Add to card" Button in WooCommerce but unable to find them.

I want to add **custom code** to choose **custom frames** for pictures people going to purchase.

Comment: WooCommerce like WordPress enable editing of the flow using filters and hooks no need to find the php file. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365050/how-to-add-filter-or-hook-for-woocommerce-add-to-cart

Comment: @add your function code so we can understand .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change the add to cart text on product archives by product types** Here is a [Complete Example](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/)

**Change this line as per your needed !**

```
case 'variable':
                return __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' );
```

**Complete code** Add the following to your `functions.php` file and edit the buttons text.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
    function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {
        global $product;

        $product_type = $product->product_type;

        switch ( $product_type ) {
            case 'external':
                return __( 'Buy product', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
            case 'grouped':
                return __( 'View products', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
            case 'simple':
                return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
            case 'variable':
                return __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' ); // Change this line 
            break;
            default:
                return __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
        }

    }
```

Comment: i am beginner to WordPress, con you please tell me where i found this function.php

Comment: @SunnyNegi you can find inside your theme folder (the theme you currently activated)

Comment: by this code only text will change, but i want to run our own functions on add to cart button

Comment: @SunnyNegi What is your own function? You should post it in the question section so we can understand that correctly .