# Woocommerce submitting additional form value via add to cart button

Tags: php, post, woocommerce, http-post, hook-woocommerce

**What I need**

I want to add to cart extra product along with main product. Additional product ID should be transmitted via POST. I want to do this **without hacking WooCommerce or using custom templates**.

**What I did**

Here's the test code with very simple input field for additional product ID.

```php
//code to add input form
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','add_additional_product');
function add_additional_product()
{
    echo "PUT ADDITIONAL ITEM ID HERE:";
    ?>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="additional_product_form">
        </div>
    <?php
}
//code to add additional item to cart
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'product_option_add_to_cart');
function product_option_add_to_cart() {
    if (isset($_POST['additional_product_form'])) {
        $product_id = $_POST['additional_product_form'];
        $found = false;
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Add to cart implementation is taken from here - [How to add filter or hook for "woocommerce_add_to_cart"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365050/how-to-add-filter-or-hook-for-woocommerce-add-to-cart) it was tested and works fine.

**What's the problem**

I want to use another hook because `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` inserts data after "X (qty) in stock" text (which placement can't be adjusted without modifying tamplates AFAIK) while I want the selection field to be before "X (qty) in stock" text. So I tried using the code via `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_additional_product', 27 );` and it doesn't work this way. So I inspected WC template (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php#L32) just to understand that `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook is already inside add to cart form there while other hooks are not. Using other hooks I can make a separate input form but how will I submit it? I searched for some JS solutions letting submit 2 forms with one button but they all involve modifying submit button.

**So the questions is:** am I left with JS to solve the issue or this can be done through PHP somehow?

Any ideas of particular PHP or JS code are welcome.

Comment: And if you use `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity`?https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php#L36

Comment: it will show input field below stock quantity cause the hook is even further in the code

Comment: in my theme both hooks are shown before. 
So you will have to look for the solution in that direction..

Comment: I think you are a little stuck. For simple products you _could_ use `add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'add_additional_product', 5 );` to display before the stock status, _but_ you will be outside of the `<form>` element entirely. You could put it there, but then I think you would need to use ajax/JS to add it to the cart when a customer clicks add to cart.

Comment: Additionally, I just wanted to point out that I think calling `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()` from the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook will result in an infinite loop (or atleast it used to)

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks. The logic inside the function prevents infinite loop. As for the hook I was going to use `(woocommerce_single_product_summary, xxx, 27)` cause it places the field in the right place. So you think as soon as it is outside `<form>` I have no chances of solving it with PHP only?

Comment: Yes, I think if it's outside the `<form>` you have to use Javascript. I would probably re-think your need to get this displayed before the stock status. How critical is that? That's  not on a hook, so the only way to move it would be a template override.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Originally I thought it can't be that way and I am missing something. Rather strange they made templates that way as inserting something inbetween "x in stock" text and button doesn't make sense for me. Now I am trying to manipulate ".stock" element with JQuery which works to some degree but is causing ugly element movement visible by page visitor.

Comment: Actually I'm just learning PHP and finding completely pluggable solution seemed to me as a good task.
So now it seems JS is inevitable: either I have to change placement of "stock" element or submit a value selected in custom form.