# WooCommerce - Overriding ajax add to cart not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to override the ajax add to cart function of WooCoommerce and add this simple condition.

```
$base = true;
if($base){
   return the default error just to test...
}else{
  default functionality ...
}
```

I get the idea from [here](https://gist.github.com/qutek/064bf7b44dfd2c6f46b2#file-woocommerce-ajax-php-L248) and simply add my condition to it just to test but it doesn't work.

```
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    check_ajax_referer( 'add-to-cart', 'security' );
    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST['product_id'] ) );
    $quantity   = empty( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', $_POST['quantity'] );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );
    
    $base = true;
    if($base){//simple condition
        header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
            // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors
            $data = array(
                'error' => true,
                'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id)
            );
        $woocommerce->set_messages();
        echo json_encode( $data );
    }else{
        if ( $passed_validation && $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );
            if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) {
                woocommerce_add_to_cart_message( $product_id );
                $woocommerce->set_messages();
            }
            // Return fragments
            woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments();  
        } else {
            header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
            // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors
            $data = array(
                'error' => true,
                'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id)
            );
            $woocommerce->set_messages();
            echo json_encode( $data );
        }
    }
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you missed the whole thing. Instead of `wp_ajax_woocommerce_add_to_cart` the action you need is [woocommerce_add_to_cart](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/actions/woocommerce_add_to_cart/) and you don't need the `wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_add_to_cart` action at all.

Instead of that [source](https://gist.github.com/qutek/064bf7b44dfd2c6f46b2#file-woocommerce-ajax-php-L248), you should be taking the idea from [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-ajax.php#L398). It is located on `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php`.

Take note of `self::get_refreshed_fragments()`, used [WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_ajaxget_refreshed_fragments/) instead.

Overall, your code should be:

```
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    ob_start();

    // phpcs:disable WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Missing
    if ( !isset( $_POST[ 'product_id' ] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST[ 'product_id' ] ) );
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $quantity = empty( $_POST[ 'quantity' ] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST[ 'quantity' ] ) );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );
    $product_status = get_post_status( $product_id );
    $variation_id = 0;
    $variation = array();

    if ( $product && 'variation' === $product->get_type() ) {
        $variation_id = $product_id;
        $product_id = $product->get_parent_id();
        $variation = $product->get_variation_attributes();
    }
    
    $base = true;
    if ( $base ) { /** Your condition here **/
        // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors.
        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id ),
        );

        wp_send_json( $data );
    } else {
        if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation ) && 'publish' === $product_status ) {

            do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );

            if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
                wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
            }

            WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();

        } else {

            // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors.
            $data = array(
                'error' => true,
                'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id ),
            );

            wp_send_json( $data );
        }
    }
    // phpcs:enable
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart' );
```

**EDIT:** You may be in a known [issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13911) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365050/how-to-add-filter-or-hook-for-woocommerce-add-to-cart)) where the action `woocommerce_add_to_cart` is being called multiple times because of the function `WC()->cart->add_to_cart(...)`.

Base on [this](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/automatically-add-product-to-cart-on-visit/) source, you can solve it by adding conditional statement so that the `WC()->cart->add_to_cart(...)` won't cause the issue.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but base on your code it looks like you just want to add another condition before adding the products into the cart.

In that case, you could do the following.

```
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    ob_start();
    
    if ( !isset( $_POST[ 'product_id' ] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $found = false;
    $base = true;
    if ( $base ) { /** Your condition here **/
        // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors.
        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id ),
        );

        wp_send_json( $data );
    }else{
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) { //check if product already in cart
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            if ( ! $found ){ // if product not found, add it
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
            }
        } else {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart(  $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation ); // if no products in cart, add it
        }
    } 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart' );
```

OR

```
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    ob_start();
    
    if ( !isset( $_POST[ 'product_id' ] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $found = false;
    $base = true;
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) { //check if product already in cart
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            if ( ! $found ){ // if product not found, add it
                if ( $base ) { /** Your condition here **/
                    $data = array(
                        'error' => true,
                        'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id ),
                    );
                    wp_send_json( $data );
                }else{
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
                }
            }
        } else {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart(  $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation ); // if no products in cart, add it
        }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart' );
```

Comment: However, for some reason, I'm having a recursive loop. Any idea?